# smart gwt- is it possible to show an external url within a window that is part of the smart gwt app

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I want to implement a scenario where, when a user visits my smart gwt based app for the first time, a popup window is shown with another url. Depending on user's action in that popup, I want to later remove the popup and add content to the main window of app.

But I could not see any way to display an external url in a window/modal window... All I saw was ways to add forms or other elements/layouts etc to a window.

Is it possible to implement the scenario I have suggested above, in Smart GWT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the HTMLPane

```
VLayout yourContentLayout = new VLayout();
HTMLPane htmlPane = new HTMLPane();
htmlPane.setContentsURL("http://www.yourSite.com/");  
htmlPane.setContentsType(ContentsType.PAGE);
yourContentLayout.addMember(htmlPane );
yourModalWindow.addItem(yourContentLayout );
```